# Sequencing and re-setting in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am actually new to SQL server 2008, and I am trying to sequence and re-set a number in a table. The source is something like:

```
Row   Refrec FLAG 
1     5      NULL  
2     4      X    
3     3      NULL 
4     2      NULL 
5     1      Y     
6     5      A    
7     4      B         
8     3      NULL  
9     2      NULL 
10    1      NULL
```

The result should look like:

```
Row   Refrec FLAG SEQUENCE
1     5      NULL  NULL 
2     4      X     0
3     3      NULL  1
4     2      NULL  2
5     1      Y     0 
6     5      A     0
7     4      B     0     
8     3      NULL  1 
9     2      NULL  2
10    1      NULL  3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the logic used to generate the `SEQUENCE` column.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to enumerate the sequence values for `NULL` values, setting all the other values to `0`.  I'm not sure why the first value is `NULL`, but that is easily fixed.

The following may do what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag is not null then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by seqnum - row order by row)
        end) as Sequence
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by flag order by row) as seqnum
      from table t
     );
```

If you really care about the first value:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row = 1 then NULL
             when flag is not null then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by seqnum - row order by row)
        end) as Sequence
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by flag order by row) as seqnum
      from table t
     );
```

Comment: +1 Although I think the row_number in the outer query should have one deducted from it, which also means the `case when flag is not null then 0` check is redundant since these will always be the first row. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a28b6/1)